# Why does my browser keep on ignoring my CSS Class?

Tags: html, css, browser, error-handling

i have been trying my best to understand why my browser keeps ignoring my css class. If i open the file path on my computer it looks just as it should, but when i put it into the hosting by FTP it shows it without the classes
My HTML:

```
<!-- FOOTER -->
<div class="divfooter">
    <img src="Images/shs-logo.png" alt="shs-logo" class="infooter">
    <img src="Images/Rooseveltka-logo.png" alt="rooseveltka-logo" class="infooter">
    <img src="Images/Logo_szu.png" alt="szu-logo" class="infooter">
    <img src="Images/upjs-LOGO.png" alt="upjs-logo" class="infooter">
    <p class="madeby">Built by Goli Golo</p>
</div>

<head>
<title>SIRIUS</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" media=”screen” />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="Images/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="Images/favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="Images/favicon-16x16.png">
<link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="Images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<style>
body,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5 {font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif}
body {font-size:16px;}
.w3-half img{margin-bottom:-6px;margin-top:16px;opacity:0.8;cursor:pointer}
.w3-half img:hover{opacity:1}
</style>
</head>
```

My CSS:

```
.divfooter {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 3%;
}

.infooter {
    padding: 4px;
    max-width: 5%;
    justify-content: center;
}

.madeby {
    padding-right: 5%;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

Every help will be hugely appreciated, i have been trying to figure it out last 2 days and cannot get my mind around it. If anything more is need i will hapily provide.
Thanks in advance,
Richarddddd.

[How it looks like on my PC locally.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmxsD.png)
[How it looks like on my hosting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaCgG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a cache issue. Try to hard refresh your page. It will clear the browser's cache and force it to load the recent version of a page.

Comment: Yes this definitely worked, thanks a lot for help. Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your css in your style tag on html page like this
`

```
<div class="divfooter">
    <img src="Images/shs-logo.png" alt="shs-logo" class="infooter">
    <img src="Images/Rooseveltka-logo.png" alt="rooseveltka-logo" class="infooter">
    <img src="Images/Logo_szu.png" alt="szu-logo" class="infooter">
    <img src="Images/upjs-LOGO.png" alt="upjs-logo" class="infooter">
    <p class="madeby">Built by Goli Golo</p>
</div>

<head>
<title>SIRIUS</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" media=”screen” />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="Images/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="Images/favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="Images/favicon-16x16.png">
<link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="Images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<style>
body,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5 {font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif}
body {font-size:16px;}
.w3-half img{margin-bottom:-6px;margin-top:16px;opacity:0.8;cursor:pointer}
.w3-half img:hover{opacity:1}
.divfooter {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 3%;
}

.infooter {
    padding: 4px;
    max-width: 5%;
    justify-content: center;
}

.madeby {
    padding-right: 5%;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
</style>
```

`

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot. 
It makes me wonder what did i do wrong while linking my css file to the html?